# What does each git command in VS Code's UI stand for?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

I have been using VS Code's UI to perform most of the commands, but I think it would be useful to now the exact git commands that VS Code performs for each item in git menu. Some of them (like "Pull") are easy to comprehend, but others (like "Stash (Include Untracked)") not that much.

[image]

If there are any git connoisseurs out there, it would be really great to have a "git representation" of each line.

Comment: Read about [`git stash`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash)

Comment: Thankfully this list uses the same terminology as git iteselft (rather than other words like "checkin"). You should be able to search for each command using the terms in the menu.

Comment: @evolutionxbox important exception from the rule is "discard all changes" which is also known for cleaning untracked files

Comment: @max630 good spot!

Answer (score 3):

Probably [this quote](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_git-output-window) from the documentation could help:

> **Git output window**
>
> You can always peek under the hood to see the Git commands we are using. This is helpful if something strange is happening or if you are just curious. :)
>
> To open the Git output window, run **View** > **Output** and select **Git** from the dropdown.